# Animation in PDF presentations, without Adobe Reader?

Tags: beamer, animations, movie15

I sometimes have to present on other people's equipment, such as machines running stripped down Linux distributions, presentation servers with a bare-bones PDF viewer running in a virtual machine, or a Windows box with a heavily locked-down Adobe Reader (e.g. with JavaScript disabled).  So far I've tried to avoid doing anything fancy with `beamer`.  But for some concepts, animations seem necessary.

> How can one create PDF presentations in LaTeX, preferably with `beamer`, which include animations that work on most PDF viewers?

Ideally, if the animations don't work then they should degrade gracefully.  For instance, the first and last frame could still be shown.

`Beamer` has `\animate` but this requires the PDF viewer to support showing several slides in succession, without manual intervention.  [Jens Nöckel suggests using external movies](http://www.uoregon.edu/~noeckel/PDFmovie.html), which seems even less likely to work; this relies on a viewer being available for the movie format, and that the movie viewer can be called by the PDF viewer.

Older documents suggest MetaPost or animated GIF files, which seem hacky (though I will consider them if no other alternatives exist).

Please discuss only one main approach per answer.

Comment: Out of curiosity: what PDF viewers except Adobe Reader are able to show animated GIFs or MetaPost? I might be mistaken but as far as I know, the answer is “none”, and your quest is hopeless.

Comment: What happened to the old answers to this question?

Comment: @Konrad: For Windows, Adobe made an Active-X control which is embedded in Office.  I guess you can watch them in Power Point.

Comment: @Charles: granted, but I guess that does’t solve this problem since this is actually the same component that’s used in Adobe Reader so if the AX control is installed chances are, so is Adobe Reader.

Comment: @Will Robertson: There have been some database errors, I'm afraid :(

Comment: Alas, I didn't see the old answers.  Konrad, would you consider turning your comment into an answer?

Comment: Why are you using PDFs to display animation?  This is why Adobe Reader is bloated.

Comment: I will reconsider, given movie15.

Comment: @András: movie15 requires not only Adobe Reader, but also an external media player and Windows. Package animate only needs Adobe Reader.

Comment: @Alexander: Rich Media works with Linux, but you need the right Flash Player. Beamer's `animate` also does not require an external media player.

Comment: @Charles: Rich Media doesn't work on Linux anymore. I was disabled (without notice) in AR 9.4.2, for security reasons probably.

Comment: @Alex: Adobe Reader 9.3.4 is still OK, I gather.  I don't think the future looks bright for Adobe support of Linux, though.

Comment: @Kevin, what other formats can TeX output to that support animations?

Comment: The simple, reliable, cross-platform solution to this is just to put a hyperlink in your pdf file and click on it to go to the animation in a browser.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

As discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428372/insert-video-clip-in-a-lyx-presentation-and-play-it-in-gnu-linux, you can use the `multimedia` package to embed movies (mpg, mp4) in a way that you can play them in Okular. Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multimedia}
\begin{document}
\movie[height = 0.6 \textwidth,width = 1.0 \textwidth]{}{animation.mpg}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1!
the only solution that worked with me so far! thanks!

Comment: Good answer. This works with `Okular` but sadly not with `impressive`:(

Comment: That's probably because `impressive` still relies on the antique Xpdf. Maybe you can ask the developer team to write a backend for the more advanced Poppler and they might be able to implement movie embedding easily.

Comment: With TeX Live 2015 and Okular Version 0.24.2 this solution does not work. There are no compilation errors, but Okular only displays a blank space.

Comment: @LuisdeSousa, both are outdated. It should work with up to date TeX Live and Okular.

Answer (score 17):

The [`movie15`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/movie15.html) package allows you to set graphics or text, including the first frame of the movie, to display if the movie is inactive.  This can be achieved with the `text` and `poster` options (taken directly from the documentation):

```
\includemovie[
  text={\includegraphics[scale=2]{path/to/poster}}
]{}{}{path/to/movie}
```

will display the image specified by `path/to/poster`, scaled to twice its size, and

```
\includemovie[
  poster,
  text={\phantom{\includegraphics[scale=2]{path/to/poster}}}
]{}{}{path/to/movie}
```

will display the first frame of the movie, and make it the size of the scaled `path/to/poster`.

This obviously doesn't make the included movie playable in any more locations than it otherwise would be, but it *does* make it more elegant when playback is unavailable.

Comment: Quick comment that [movie15](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/movie15) has been superseded by [media9](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/media9), after this answer was posted.

Answer (score 12):

The easiest way to produce animations from image sequences (pdf, mps
[metapost], jpeg, png, jb2 with pdflatex; ps/eps, mps with latex) or
inline images (pstricks, tikz) is to use the animate package. Depending
on the option settings, poster=first or poster=last, bare-bone viewers
without JavaScript, such as Xpdf, GV or GSview will display the
corresponding animation frame. For playback, however, Adobe Reader is
indispensable. Animated Gif must be split into png or eps sequence
before embedding, because it is not supported by the PDF specification.

http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/animate/animate.pdf

Answer (score 9):

This is a somewhat different approach to rendering animations or movies in Linux Latex Beamer presentations:

- Firstly I use [Kazam](https://launchpad.net/kazam) to convert any animations into more compressed mp4
- Secondly, I use `\href{run:./directory/file.mp4}{MOVIE}` in Latex/Lyx to generate the link within a pdf file.
- Thirdly I use [mpv](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mpv) as a media player.

Its config file in `/etc/mpv/mpv.conf` has just the one line: use-filedir-conf. Then, one can set in the beamer presentation directory a file called mpv.conf  with lines such as this:

```
screen=1
geometry=60%+380+80
```

- The `screen=1` allows the file.mp4 to played on the extended desktop such as the projector.
- The `geometry=` line allows one to set the magnification and the position of the window in which the movie will be rendered.

More details can be found in the mpv manual.

Finally, I use [Impressive](http://impressive.sourceforge.net/) to render the pdf.
Altogether a very pleasant way of saying goodbye to acroread and Adobe.