# Curiosity - 3D animation in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, animations

Is it possible to create animations shown in the link below in TikZ
http://ubcsanskrit.ca/lesson2/writingtutor.html

to start animation click on any of the letters on the page. I know it may not be nice to ask outside TeX question but to product such animation what sort of program one should use?
I would really appreciate your help

Comment: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/animations/

Comment: "what sort of program one should use": It appears that the website you linked uses Adobe Flash.

Comment: Have a look at this question as well: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/429/animation-in-pdf-presentations-without-adobe-reader/55623#55623

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [`animate`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/animate) package - it has a number of nice examples of animations created using TikZ and PSTricks.