# How to make your gif animation run on beamer and on a pdf file?

Tags: animations, overleaf, gif

I found this MWE of a gif animnation on tex stackexchange https://www.overleaf.com/read/zxbnyqtwvhsy

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \animategraphics[loop,controls,width=5cm]{20}{Monopole_anim-}{0}{29}
  \caption{\url{https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=37036050}} 
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

But I couldn't make it run. It get stuck on the first picture. Can you make it run ?

Can you tell me how to make it run on pdf outside overleaf ?

Comment: Did you split the gif animation into many single pictures?

Comment: Yes I did as it demonstrated in the overleaf, I split it to multiple png pictures, but the gif simply doesn't move at all

Comment: I just found an alternative, I replaced the gif by a mp4 animation and it worked locally, but still it is not a clean move https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/429/animation-in-pdf-presentations-without-adobe-reader

Comment: Animations require javascript support in the viewer, there are similar requirements for embedded video. So not every pdf viewer will do. Most does not support javascript at all (even ef they the self are written in javascript)

Comment: I just tested the linked overleaf project (https://www.overleaf.com/read/zxbnyqtwvhsy) and it works. You have to download the PDF to your computer and open it with Adobe Reader.